Txn with nested safes
// Get the signature from OWNER_1_ADDRESS
const signatureOwner1 = safeTransaction.getSignature(OWNER_1_ADDRESS) as EthSafeSignature

// Get the transaction hash of the safeTransaction
const safeTransactionHash = await protocolKit.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction)

// Instantiate the API Kit
// Use the chainId where you have the Safe account deployed
const apiKit = new SafeApiKit({ chainId })

// Propose the transaction
await apiKit.proposeTransaction({
  safeAddress: SAFE_3_4_ADDRESS,
  safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
  safeTxHash: safeTransactionHash,
  senderAddress: signerAddress,
  senderSignature: buildSignatureBytes([signatureOwner1])
})

We are getting checksum error while proposing the transaction!

Is it necessary to use API kit?
Or do we need to deploy our own tx Service? (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure)

API failing: https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global/api/v1/safes/{safeAddress}/multisig-transactions/
API ERROR:
{
  arguments: [${safeAddress}]
  code: 1,
  message: "Checksum address validation failed"
}


For checksumming your address you can use a service like https://ethsum.netlify.app/ or paste your address in etherscan to get the checksummed version.
Hope it answered your question! If yes don't hesitate to mark it solved 
Best, Louis
